# Update desde Suma de campos Sql Server y uso de isNull

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, tsql

Hace unos días que vengo renegando con una consulta en *SQL server* y la verdad es que ya no se me ocurre como seguir. Estoy convencido que se puede hacer de forma sencilla pero no cuento con los conocimientos necesario todavía. Paso a detallar:

Tengo 3 tablas. Una tabla producto con varias columnas pero solo una es el que me interesa actualizar, que se llama "pedidos". Otra tabla que se llama "detalle pedido" donde tengo 2 columnas una "idProducto" y otra "cantidad" y una ultima que se llama pedidos donde tengo distintos estados (pedido realizado, pagado, entregado).

**NECESITO:** Hacer un update a la columna "pedidos" de la tabla producto con la suma de las cantidades de la tabla "detalle pedido" a cada producto, y a su vez que si el resultado es null que la actualice a cero. Siempre y cuando el estado del pedido sea distinto a "entregado" (estado 2).

Hice varias pruebas, llegue a que actualice tanto cuando agrego pedidos como cuando resto EXCEPTO cuando llega a 0 que no actualiza y deja la columna igual al ultimo numero que tenia. Probé con el siguiente código pero no funciona.

```
update Producto 
set Producto.pedidos = suma.suma from(
select SUM(isnull(DetallePedido.cantidad,1)) AS suma, DetallePedido.idProducto
from DetallePedido
inner join Pedido on Pedido.idDetallePedido = DetallePedido.id
where Pedido.idEstado=1
group by idProducto
) as suma
```

Es mi primer posteo en esta pagina, y lo estoy realizando después de buscar por muchos lugares sin encontrar alguna solución parecida. Perdón si es una pregunta repetida.

Comment: podes agregar un ejemplo con datos, que tenes y como queres que quede, a ver si podemos ayudarte un poco mas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la consulta si cantidad es null debe convertirse en 0 no en 1.
En el JOIN hace falta la condición que vincule los registros con el producto.

```
UPDATE producto 
SET    pedidos = (SELECT Sum(Isnull(cantidad, 0)) -- cantidad = 0 si es null 
                  FROM   pedido p 
                         INNER JOIN detallepedido dp 
                                 ON p.id = dp.idpedido 
                                    -- enlazar el idproducto 
                                    AND dp.idproducto = producto.id
                  WHERE  p.idestado = 1)
```